# Function to extract intersections of crossing lines on axes

Tags: perl, optimization

Code in Perl is 5.18.2.

```
sub extract_crossing {
    my @x = @{ $_[0] }; my @y = @{ $_[1] };
    my @xcross =(); my @ycross =();
    for (my $i=0; $i<$#x; $i++) {
        my $k = ($y[$i] - $y[$i+1]) / ($x[$i] - $x[$i+1]);
        if($y[$i+1] * $y[$i] < 0) {
            my $xc = $x[$i+1] - $y[$i+1] / $k;
            push(@xcross, $xc);
        }
        if($x[$i+1] * $x[$i] < 0) {
            my $yc = $y[$i+1] - $x[$i+1] * $k;
            push(@ycross, $yc);
        }
    }
    return (\@xcross, \@ycross);
}
```

which extracts successfully crossing points with x- and y-axes. 
It looks first point where the product of two subsequent points is negative. 
If so, intersection point with corresponding axis.

However, I feel this function extraneous, since it is so basic operation.

**How can you do this extraction better with default tools in Perl?**

Comment: What do you want improved? Runtime? Readability? And what are default tools? Is `List::MoreUtils` a default tool?

Comment: Also, you might have a bug if you're not operating on a torus. You might want to start your loop at one, or use `$i+1` and `$i` instead of `$i` and `$i-1` for indices since you're getting a negative result in the iteration and that means it takes from the end of the array.

Comment: @patrick Yes, moreutils is default. Both runtime and readabilty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `List::MoreUtils` qualifies as one of Perl's "default tools" as you say in a comment, [`Math::Geometry::Planar`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Geometry::Planar) should qualify as well. `Math::Geometry::Planar` provides a number of handy functions for calculating the intersection of segments, rays, and lines, as well as functions for manipulating polygons, calculating distances, and other goodies.

When evaluating any solution, you should make sure it generates correct results for a number of inputs, including edge cases. Your original code has at least one bug (a divide-by-zero error for vertical line segments)...let's make sure [`SegmentLineIntersection`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Geometry::Planar#SegmentLineIntersection-p1-p2-p3-p4) from `Math::Geometry::Planar` works as expected:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::Geometry::Planar qw(SegmentLineIntersection);
use Test::More tests => 8;

my @x_axis = ( [0, 0], [1, 0] );
my @y_axis = ( [0, 0], [0, 1] );

is_deeply(
    SegmentLineIntersection([ [-1, 2], [2, -1], @x_axis ]),
    [1, 0],
    'Segment (-1, 2), (2, -1) intersects x-axis once at (1, 0)'
);

is_deeply(
    SegmentLineIntersection([ [-1, 2], [2, -1], @y_axis ]),
    [0, 1],
    'Segment (-1, 2), (2, -1) intersects y-axis once at (0, 1)'
);

is(
    SegmentLineIntersection([ [0, 1], [1, 1], @x_axis ]),
    0,
    'Horizontal segment above x-axis never intersects x-axis'
);

is(
    SegmentLineIntersection([ [1, 0], [1, 1], @y_axis ]),
    0,
    'Vertical segment to the right of y-axis never intersects y-axis'
);

is(
    SegmentLineIntersection([ [0, 0], [1, 0], @x_axis ]),
    0,
    'Horizontal segment on x-axis returns false (intersects infinite times)'
);

is(
    SegmentLineIntersection([ [0, 0], [0, 1], @y_axis ]),
    0,
    'Vertical segment on y-axis returns false (intersects infinite times)'
);

is_deeply(
    SegmentLineIntersection([ [0, 0], [1, 1], @x_axis ]),
    [0, 0],
    'Segment beginning at origin intersects x-axis at (0, 0)'
);

is_deeply(
    SegmentLineIntersection([ [0, 0], [1, 1], @y_axis ]),
    [0, 0],
    'Segment beginning at origin intersects y-axis at (0, 0)'
);
```

#### Output:

```
1..8
ok 1 - Segment (-1, 2), (2, -1) intersects x-axis once at (1, 0)
ok 2 - Segment (-1, 2), (2, -1) intersects y-axis once at (0, 1)
ok 3 - Horizontal segment above x-axis never intersects x-axis
ok 4 - Vertical segment to the right of y-axis never intersects y-axis
ok 5 - Horizontal segment on x-axis returns false (intersects infinite times)
ok 6 - Vertical segment on y-axis returns false (intersects infinite times)
not ok 7 - Segment beginning at origin intersects x-axis at (0, 0)
#   Failed test 'Segment beginning at origin intersects x-axis at (0, 0)'
#   at geometry line 49.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got = '0'
#     $expected = ARRAY(0x1b1f088)
not ok 8 - Segment beginning at origin intersects y-axis at (0, 0)
#   Failed test 'Segment beginning at origin intersects y-axis at (0, 0)'
#   at geometry line 55.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got = '0'
#     $expected = ARRAY(0x1b1f010)
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 8.
```

Looks like our last two tests failed: apparently segments with one end on a line don't count as intersecting (this is the case in your original algorithm as well). I'm not a geometry expert, so I can't evaluate whether this is a bug or mathematically correct.

### Calculating intercepts for multiple segments

The following function returns the x-intercepts for multiple connected line segments. The implementation for calculating y-intercepts would be nearly identical. Note that if a pair of segments meet exactly on the axis, it doesn't count as an intercept, as in your original function. That may or may not be desirable.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::Geometry::Planar qw(SegmentLineIntersection);
use Test::Exception;
use Test::More tests => 3;

sub x_intercepts {
    my ($points) = @_;

    die 'Must pass at least 2 points' unless @$points >= 2;

    my @intercepts;
    my @x_axis = ( [0, 0], [1, 0] );

    foreach my $i (0 .. $#$points - 1) {
        my $intersect = SegmentLineIntersection([ @$points[$i, $i + 1], @x_axis ]);
        push @intercepts, $intersect if $intersect;
    }

    return \@intercepts;
}

dies_ok { x_intercepts([ [0, 0] ]) } 'Dies with < 2 points';

is_deeply(
    x_intercepts([ [-1, -1], [1, 1], [1, -1] ]),
    [ [0, 0], [1, 0] ],
    'Intersects x-axis at (0, 0) and (1, 0)'
);

is_deeply(
    x_intercepts([ [-1, -1], [0, 0], [1, 1] ]),
    [],
    "No intercept when segments start or end on x-axis but don't cross it"
);
```

#### Output:

```
1..3
ok 1 - Dies with < 2 points
ok 2 - Intersects x-axis at (0, 0) and (1, 0)
ok 3 - No intercept when segments start or end on x-axis but don't cross it
```

Note that this implementation accepts a single array reference of points, where a point is a reference to a two-element array, instead of separate array references of x- and y-coordinates. I think this is a little bit more intuitive.

Comment: Can you give an example how to combine these tests the ruling part of the function in the body, please? The failing of the last two tests is not a bug. It is a mathematical feature.

Comment: @Masi I added an implementation for calculating the x-intercepts of multiple contiguous segments.

Comment: Which package has this `Math::Geometry::Planar`? I switched to OSX and cannot this this working in this environment. I opened the OSX issue here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/186636/15504

Comment: @Masi Use `cpan`: `cpan Math::Geometry::Planar`

Comment: @Masi I'm not sure what you mean when you say "I replaced the function in the body with your function..." I would recommend posting a new question that shows the exact code you're using and the error you get. Comments aren't really suitable for posting long snippets of code since they are quite difficult to read.

Comment: Excellent answer.  Great module.  ++ for using tests in such a simple and useful way.

Answer (score 3):

This is one alternative solution.
The code in the question calculates the value of `$k` every iteration, that's way too often, since you'll only need it if you want to store the value in one of the return arrays.
This code loops over the indices from `0` to `$#x-1` and makes use of the fact that the index is always stored in `$_`. This way, you some sort of lazy evaluation.
Also I'm not sure if it is a bug, but in the first iteration of the `for` loop in the OP the comparison is `$y[-1] * $y[0] > 0`. This code doesn't do that.

```
use 5.010;              # for the // iterator
sub extract_crossing2 {
  my @x = @{ $_[0] }; my @y = @{ $_[1] };
  my (@xcross, @ycross);
  # "lazily" calculate $k,
  # there is a possibility of division by zero here! maybe catch that 
  # with if (defined $@){…}
  my $get_k = sub {
    eval {($y[$_] - $y[$_+1]) / ($x[$_] - $x[$_+1])}
  };
  foreach (0..$#x-1){
    my $k;        # only gets set if needed
    push @xcross, ($x[$_] - $y[$_]) / ($k  = $get_k->()) if $y[$_] * $y[$_+1] < 0;
    push @ycross, ($y[$_] - $x[$_]) * ($k // $get_k->()) if $x[$_] * $x[$_+1] < 0;
  }
  return \(@xcross, @ycross);
}
```

There might be a nice solution with the `pair*` routines provided by `List::MoreUtils` and `List::Util`.

**Edit**: As [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) has pointed out, there is a possibility of a division by zero error in the question's code. I didn't work around that error.

Comment: There is some bug in the code. I get completely different solution than the function in the body. Pair routines would be nice to see. Can you make this without 5.010, by the newest Perl? It would be make it more extensible.

Comment: @Masi: Perl `v5.10.0` is about eight years old now. And you can use it with any newer version. You just need at least 5.10.0 for the `//` "defined or" operator, but any newer one will do. Which are the modules that you need 5.8.x for?

Comment: @Masi: yeah I switched x and y for the y crossing part. now it should be the same.

Comment: I realize these are bugs in the OP's implementation, but you'll get divide by zero errors if the line is vertical; and no intersection or only an x- or y-value will be returned for lines that start on the axes (by design?).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot In each iteration of loop, `if ($k ==0) break;` enough to fix the bug? But then can we have only `my $k;` inside the for -loop.