# How to use join?

Tags: arrays, perl, list, perl-data-structures

Minimal code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30176841/54964) and its `join` statement

```
my @x = qw/10 20 30 40/;
my @y = qw/60 70 8 90 10/;
my @input_list = (@x, @y);

print "Before join @input_list \n";

print join ",", @$_ for @input_list ;

print "After join @input_list \n";
```

which gives

```
Before join 20 40 60 80 120 140 16 180 20 
After join 20 40 60 80 120 140 16 180 20
```

but in `use strict;`

> Can't use string ("10") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at
>   test4.pl line 10.

`join` joins separate strings of array in [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html). 
Here the code tries to join comma apparently with each hash (`@$_`) of the array item. 
However, this seems to be happening.

**Why is this error here in the minimum code?**

Comment: Your entire statement `@$_ for @input_list ;` is both incorrect and unnecessary. `join` accepts a delimiter and a list, just pass `@input_list` directly to `join`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen @masi in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30176841/54964) `@intercept_list` was an **reference**  to an array of anonymous arrays (built from `@input_list`) and you were using  `join` on the **de-referenced elements** - *i.e* `@$_`.

Comment: In general, rather than stringing together a series of very long questions you should focus your posts in a way that helps you understand the problem - **and then focus on understanding the solution**.  This question is better than the [one you refer to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30176841/54964)  (which won't get a lot of up votes in its current form - I hope you can improve it). I speak from my own experience of withdrawn and down voted questions here, but I do think keeping questions short and focused helps improve the quality of SO resources: both questions and answers.

Comment: I am just as guilty for following up with too numerous comments in the other thread. I am going to remove them and the ones I have made here after 24 hours. *mea culpa*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, what you're doing here:

```
print join ",", @$_ for @input_list ;
```

Isn't working, because it's:

- iterating `@input_list` extracting each element into `$_`.
- Dereferencing `$_` pretending it's an array `@$_`.

This is basically the same as trying to:

```
print join ( ",", @{"10"} );
```

Which makes no sense, and so doesn't work.

```
my $string = join ( ",", @input_list );
print $string;
```

Will do the trick.

The thing that you're missing here I think, is this:

```
use Data::Dumper; 
my @x = qw/10 20 30 40/;
my @y = qw/60 70 8 90 10/;
my @input_list = (@x, @y);
print Dumper \@input_list;
```

Isn't generating a multi-dimensional list. It's a single dimensional one.

```
$VAR1 = [
          '10',
          '20',
          '30',
          '40',
          '60',
          '70',
          '8',
          '90',
          '10'
        ];
```

I suspect what you may want is:

```
my @x = qw/10 20 30 40/;
my @y = qw/60 70 8 90 10/;
my @input_list = (\@x, \@y);
```

Or perhaps:

```
my $x_ref = [ qw/10 20 30 40/ ];
my $y_ref = [ qw/60 70 8 90 10/ ];
my @input_list = ($x_ref, $y_ref );
```

Which makes `@input_list`:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '10',
            '20',
            '30',
            '40'
          ],
          [
            '60',
            '70',
            '8',
            '90',
            '10'
          ]
        ];
```

Then your 'for' loop works:

```
print join (",", @$_),"\n" for @input_list ;
```

Because then, `@input_list` is actually 2 items - two array references that you can then dereference and join.

As a slight word of warning though - one of the gotchas that can occur when doing:

```
my @input_list = (\@x, \@y);
```

Because you're inserting references to `@x` and `@y` - if you reuse either of these, then you'll change the content of `@input_list` - which is why it's probably better to use the `my @input_list = ( $x_ref, $y_ref );`.

Comment: Excellent addition! It seems to solve my bug `Can't use string ("22.875451") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /Library/Perl/5.18/Math/Geometry/Planar.pm line 622.`

Comment: I got now this error `/Users/code/data.txt : Can't use string ("2") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /Library/Perl/5.18/Math/Geometry/Planar.pm line 622.` Is this related to the warning which you added?

Comment: No it'll be the same problem - the code is expecting an array reference and it's getting a single value ("2"). Likely root cause is again - a single dimensional array being passed instead of a multi-dimensional one.

Answer (score 4):

```
my @x = qw/10 20 30 40/;
my @y = qw/60 70 8 90 10/;
my @input_list = (@x, @y);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
my @input_list = qw/10 20 30 40 60 70 8 90 10/;
```

To create an array of arrays, use references:

```
my @input_list = (\@x, \@y);
```

The rest of your code then works as expected.